# Rest-assured custom header

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured

In the photo below, I'm sending a custom header and get a response, and it works just fine with Postman.

[image: Photo from Postman test]
However, when I'm trying to test with `rest-assured`, I get `401 Unauthorized` status code.

```
authToken = getAuthTokenForUsnAndPwd("usn", "pwd");

expect().statusCode(200).given()
    .header("auth_token", authToken)
    .when().get(restResource + "private/entries");
```

What am I doing wrong?

And how to make test for POST method with JSON object?

```
JSONObject e = new JSONObject();
e.put("info", "info");

expect().statusCode(200).given()
     .contentType("application/json").body(e.toString())
     .header("auth_token", authToken)
     .when().post(restResource + "private/entries");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect().
    statusCode(200).
given().
    auth().preemptive().oauth2(authToken).body(e.toString()).
with().
    contentType(JSON).
when().
    post(restResource + "private/entries");
```